# Inverting result of select query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table called "products", with the following data.

```
--------------------
| id | tag_name    |
--------------------
| 1  | electronics |
| 1  | tv          | 
| 1  | lcd         |
| 2  | tv          | 
| 2  | lcd         |
| 3  | tv          |
| 3  | lcd         |
--------------------
```

It is mandatory that all the products have a "electronics" tag, but few of the products are missing that tag. Based on the data above my question, what query do I run so that it will return ids 2 & 3 as they don't have an 'electronics' tag.

2 solutions that come to mind are

1. Using a NOT IN -  `select distinct id from products where id not in (select id from products where tag_name='electronics')` - with a good few million rows this is quite inefficient
2. Second solution is to cobble up a script which selects all distinct ids and then checks if "electronics" tag exists for that id, inserting the row if not.

Is there another more efficient way of handling this? (may be using a `JOIN` on the same table)

Comment: One approach would be to delete all `electronics` tags and then readd them for all ids

Comment: @Dancrumb: or create unique composite index (there should be one anyway) and insert with ignore :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO products 
SELECT a.id, 'electronics'
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products b ON a.id = b.id AND b.tag_name = 'electronics'
WHERE b.id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will actually update the `products` table to give the 'electronics' tag to all products which don't have it.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f312a/1/0

However, if you only wish to *select* the `id`s which don't have the particular tag, then use zerkms's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182241/1446794).

Comment: you also liked sqlfiddle, didn't you? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, yes it's a great tool for demonstration! =)

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` will not work on your case since not all `id`s have `electronics` *tag_name* on it.

Just give this a try:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM Products
GROUP BY id
  HAVING not GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name) like CONCAT('%','electronics','%')
```

**[view here from demo: SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20856/9)**

Comment: `JOIN` won't, but `LEFT JOIN` will. This query doesn't have any chance to be optimized and in any way will cause table fullscan

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM products t1
LEFT JOIN products t2 ON t2.tag_name = 'electronics' AND t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d805/2

Comment: * Cleaned up the comments, I've been told bullshit and now I do realise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, I tried it locally and it appeared to work

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.id 
    FROM products p1 
    LEFT JOIN products p2 ON p1.id = p2.id AND p1.tag_name != p2.tag_name 
WHERE p1.tag_name != 'electronics' and p2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: this will select id = 1 as well. because 1) tv != lcd 2) tv (or lcd) != electronics

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, have you tested it locally to confirm that result?

Comment: the query is trivial, so I don't see any reasons to reproduce it. Isn't that obvious for you?

Comment: Then you would know it's not resulting in id = 1

Comment: it will, because: 1) tv != lcd 2) tv (or lcd) != electronics. rows with id = 1 fits both join condition and one where condition

Comment: That's what DISTINCT id is for ;) If you're so persistent about its invalidity, I urge you to just create a small table and prove yourself correct or incorrect, stop arguing until you know the facts of the results

Comment: distinct is applied **AFTER** where and join. So it doesn't change if `id = 1` will be selected or not

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128b2/2 --- I will even show that to you. And compare with mine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128b2/3 "I urge you to just create a small table and prove yourself correct or incorrect, stop arguing until you know the facts of the results" --- made my morning. Thanks for good mood :-)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d805/4 --- now it doesn't work at all :-) For another *obvious* reason :-)